# Why is my constant mock with python unit test not working

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I use some mocking code to mock a constant in python. I read the docs over and over again but I don't see what I do wrong:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

from sync_servicenowjira.adapter_sn_to_jira import adapt_sn_to_jira
from sync_servicenowjira.constants import DOWNLOAD_PATH
from sync_servicenowjira.dao_service_now import get_service_now_tickets

# @mock.patch('sync_servicenowjira.constants.DOWNLOAD_PATH', './test_files/')
class Test(TestCase):

    def test_adapt_sn_to_jira(self):
        with mock.patch('sync_servicenowjira.constants.DOWNLOAD_PATH', './test_files/'):
            test = DOWNLOAD_PATH
            print(test)

            sn_tickets = get_service_now_tickets(True)
            jira_tickets = adapt_sn_to_jira(sn_tickets)

            self.assertIsInstance(jira_tickets, list)
            self.assertGreater(len(jira_tickets), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to mock out the reference in the code under test, not the original reference. Assuming you did `from .constants import DOWNLOAD_PATH` in `dao_service_now.py`, you would do: `mock.patch('sync_servicenowjira.dao_service_now.DOWNLOAD_PATH', './test_files/')`

Comment: This is a strange concept, but let me try to explain further. When you load the test code, first thing that happens is that it will hit all of the import lines. Each file will be imported once, and at that time, each import will copy references to objects they import. When the patch code runs, the reference to the object in the constants file has already been copied, so even though you update the original definition, that patch does not overwrite the reference already copied by `dao_service_now` during the import.

Comment: Well, it works. Please elaborate in an answer so I can accept it :)